# What is an equivalent of Swift's UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity, spritekit

Basically, I am from a Swift SpriteKit background where `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` is a CGRect which represents the screen and can be manipulated in various ways like getting the middle of the screen by using

```
var screenCenter = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2)
```

What is an equivalent of UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds in Unity (C# Scripting) that can manipulated to get various positions in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [the Screen class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html):

```
var screenCenter = new Vector2(
                         Screen.width,
                         Screen.height,
                       ) * 0.5f;
```

Note that this will give you the pixel coordinates of the center of the screen, *in screenspace*. To translate this into a position within the world coordinate system, you'll want to use something like [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).